# React. Фото из локального json файла не отображается при map

Tags: reactjs

Есть локальный json файл, где данные про продукт.
Мне нужно импортировать фото, имя, цену и т.д.
Всё отображается, кроме фото. Как правильно написать что бы путь к локальному фото был протён?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Я пытаюсь с помощью map добраться до каждого элемента json файла, и передать данные в слайдер.
Вот таким образом:                 {
                  bestsellers.map((a, i)=>(
                    <SwiperSlide className="bswiper" key={i}>
                      <img src={a.image} alt={a.name} onClick={() => moreAbout()} />
                    </SwiperSlide>
                  ))
                }

И вот где <img src={a.image} /> фотоне отображается.

Answer (score 1):

Вот JSON:

```
{
"id": 0,
"year": 2019,
"make": "34,888",
"model": "Volkswagen Tiguan",
"trim": "Diesel",
"mileage": "19,855 km",
"image": "car-1"
```

}

Это map:

```
{
      Records.map(car => (
        <li key={car.id}>
        <img src={require(`../../image/images/${car.image}.jpg`)} alt="car"/>
          <p>
            <span>{car.year}{' '}</span>{car.model}
          </p>
          <p>{car.mileage}{' | '}Automatic{' | '}{car.trim}</p>
          <p>${car.make}</p>
        </li>
      ))
    }
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]